# How to convert an array to String format without commas/brackets and add parentheses as values

Tags: java, arrays, string

I want to take the array of random values I've generated and print the aforementioned array with parentheses outside the longest run of the same number.
For example, if the array was [0,1,1,1,2,4,7,4] I'd like to receive 0(111)2474 as an output.

This is my code thus far.

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Arrays;

/**
 * Write a description of class ArrayRunner1 here.
 * 
 * @author Ibrahim Khan
 * @version (a version number or a date)
 */
public class ArrayRunner1 {

    /**
     * This method will generate my random numbers for my array. 
     * @param min minimum random value wanted
     * @param max maximum random value wanted
     * @return randomNum a random number between 1 and 6 inclusive
     */
    public static int randInt(int min, int max) {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int randomNum = rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
        return randomNum;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("\f");


        //Part 1 - Generate a random array of length 40 with random 1-6 inclusive
        int[] array1 = new int[40];
        for (int i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
            array1[i] = randInt(1, 6);
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array1));

        //Counts and RETURN: reports how many times each number is present
        int counter1 = 0;
        int counter2 = 0;
        int counter3 = 0;
        int counter4 = 0;
        int counter5 = 0;
        int counter6 = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
            if (array1[i] == 1) {
                counter1++;
            }
            if (array1[i] == 2) {
                counter2++;
            }
            if (array1[i] == 3) {
                counter3++;
            }
            if (array1[i] == 4) {
                counter4++;
            }
            if (array1[i] == 5) {
                counter5++;
            }
            if (array1[i] == 6) {
                counter6++;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("There are " + counter1 + " ones.");
        System.out.println("There are " + counter2 + " twos.");
        System.out.println("There are " + counter3 + " threes.");
        System.out.println("There are " + counter4 + " fours.");
        System.out.println("There are " + counter5 + " fives.");
        System.out.println("There are " + counter6 + " sixes.");

        //Counts the longest run of the same number. A run continues only when consecutive numbers have the same value.   
        //RETURN: The repeated number and the length of the run is then printed
        int counter = 1;
        int runMax = 1;
        int runMin = 0;
        int variableNum = 0;
        int startCounter = 0;
        int endCounter = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < array1.length - 1; i++) {

            if (array1[i] == array1[i + 1]) {
                counter++;

                if (counter >= runMax {
                    runMax = counter;
                    runMin = i - counter + 1;
                    variableNum = array1[i];
                    startCounter = i - counter + 2;
                    endCounter = i + counter - 1;
                }
                } else {
                    counter = 1;

                }


            }
            System.out.println("The longest run is " + runMax + " times and the number is " + variableNum + ". ");
            System.out.println("The run starts at " + startCounter + " and ends at " + endCounter);




            //Prints the array with parentheses outside the longest run, if there is more than one max run, use the last one. 
        }
    }
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Yes you posted your entire code, but it does not include any attempt you've made at solving your question.

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;

public class Snippet {
    /**
     * This method will generate my random numbers for my array.
     * 
     * @param min
     *            minimum random value wanted
     * @param max
     *            maximum random value wanted
     * @return randomNum a random number between 1 and 6 inclusive
     */
    public static int randInt(int min, int max) {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int randomNum = rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
        return randomNum;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("\f");

        // Part 1 - Generate a random array of length 40 with random 1-6
        // inclusive
        int[] array1 = new int[40];
        for (int i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
            array1[i] = randInt(1, 6);
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array1));

        // Counts and RETURN: reports how many times each number is present
        int counter1 = 0;
        int counter2 = 0;
        int counter3 = 0;
        int counter4 = 0;
        int counter5 = 0;
        int counter6 = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
            if (array1[i] == 1) {
                counter1++;
            }
            if (array1[i] == 2) {
                counter2++;
            }
            if (array1[i] == 3) {
                counter3++;
            }
            if (array1[i] == 4) {
                counter4++;
            }
            if (array1[i] == 5) {
                counter5++;
            }
            if (array1[i] == 6) {
                counter6++;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("There are " + counter1 + " ones.");
        System.out.println("There are " + counter2 + " twos.");
        System.out.println("There are " + counter3 + " threes.");
        System.out.println("There are " + counter4 + " fours.");
        System.out.println("There are " + counter5 + " fives.");
        System.out.println("There are " + counter6 + " sixes.");

        // Counts the longest run of the same number. A run continues only when
        // consecutive numbers have the same value.
        // RETURN: The repeated number and the length of the run is then printed
        int counter = 1;
        int runMax = 0;
        int runMin = 0;
        int variableNum = 0;
        int startCounter = 0;
        int endCounter = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < array1.length - 1; i++) {

            if (array1[i] == array1[i + 1]) {
                counter++;

                if (counter >= runMax) {
                    runMax = counter;
                    startCounter = i - counter +2;
                    // runMin = i-counter+1;
                    variableNum = array1[i];
                    endCounter = i+1;
                }
            } else {
                counter = 1;

            }

        }
        System.out.println("The longest run is " + runMax
                + " times and the number is " + variableNum + ". ");
        System.out.println("The run starts at " + startCounter
                + " and ends at " + endCounter);

        for (int i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
            if (i==startCounter) {
                System.out.print("(");
            }
            System.out.print(array1[i]);
            if (i==endCounter) {
                System.out.print(")");
            }
        }
        System.out.println();

        // Prints the array with parentheses outside the longest run, if there
        // is more than one max run, use the last one.
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm having some difficulties with getting the parentheses to start and end at the right spot. Is this a problem with my startCounter and endCounter? I've tried messing with it quite a bit, but it doesn't seem to work. The for statement works perfecly though, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Okay. I think I have this. The first answer was close, but if you run the program a few times, you discover issues. There is a logic error somewhere in your above code, but I have a work around. I think it is how you get the endCounter. It seems to count odd. But I got the program to work as far as I can tell. Try this out. I have run it several times and it seems consistent.

import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Arrays;

/**
 * Write a description of class ArrayRunner1 here.
 * 
 * @author Ibrahim Khan
 * @version (a version number or a date)
 */
public class ArrayRunner1 {

```
/**
 * This method will generate my random numbers for my array. 
 * @param min minimum random value wanted
 * @param max maximum random value wanted
 * @return randomNum a random number between 1 and 6 inclusive
 */
public static int randInt(int min, int max) {
    Random rand = new Random();
    int randomNum = rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
    return randomNum;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("\f");


    //Part 1 - Generate a random array of length 40 with random 1-6 inclusive
    int[] array1 = new int[40];
    for (int i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
        array1[i] = randInt(1, 6);
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array1));

    //Counts and RETURN: reports how many times each number is present
    int counter1 = 0;
    int counter2 = 0;
    int counter3 = 0;
    int counter4 = 0;
    int counter5 = 0;
    int counter6 = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
        if (array1[i] == 1) {
            counter1++;
        }
        if (array1[i] == 2) {
            counter2++;
        }
        if (array1[i] == 3) {
            counter3++;
        }
        if (array1[i] == 4) {
            counter4++;
        }
        if (array1[i] == 5) {
            counter5++;
        }
        if (array1[i] == 6) {
            counter6++;
        }
    }

    System.out.println("There are " + counter1 + " ones.");
    System.out.println("There are " + counter2 + " twos.");
    System.out.println("There are " + counter3 + " threes.");
    System.out.println("There are " + counter4 + " fours.");
    System.out.println("There are " + counter5 + " fives.");
    System.out.println("There are " + counter6 + " sixes.");

    //Counts the longest run of the same number. A run continues only when consecutive numbers have the same value.   
    //RETURN: The repeated number and the length of the run is then printed
    int counter = 1;
    int runMax = 1;
    int runMin = 0;
    int variableNum = 0;
    int startCounter = 0;
    int endCounter = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < array1.length - 1; i++) {

        if (array1[i] == array1[i + 1]) {
            counter++;

            if (counter >= runMax ){

                runMax = counter;
                runMin = i - counter ;// was plus one I cahnged this.
                variableNum = array1[i];
                startCounter = i - counter + 2;
                endCounter = i + counter -1;
            }
            } else {
                counter = 1;

            }


        }
        System.out.println("The longest run is " + runMax + " times and the number is " + variableNum + ". ");
        System.out.println("The run starts at " + startCounter + " and ends at " + endCounter);




        //Prints the array with parentheses outside the longest run, if there is more than one max run, use the last one. 
        String output = "";// added this
        for(int x = 0; x < array1.length; x++)
        {
              if( x == startCounter)
              {
                    output += "("+array1[x];
              }
              else if( x == startCounter + runMax )
              {
                    else if( x == startCounter + runMax )
              {
                    if(x == array1.length-1)
                    {
                          output += ")";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                          output += ")"+array1[x];
                    }
              }
              else
              {
                    output += array1[x];
              }
        }
        System.out.print("\n"+output);
       }
}
```

Comment: There is one issue with this solution. There is some oddity with how the output is before the array is printed out. Sometimes, you will say that the longest run is 2 but the starting index and the ending index will be a value of 3. For example, it will say that the starting index is 2, but the ending index is 6, not five as expected. Other times it will say that the starting index is 2 and the ending will be 5 for a run of 3.. This tends to happen at the end boundaries. You fix that and tweak the code I gave you and you should be set

Comment: As you have observered yourself your code to calculate the startCounter/endCounter is wrong. You can see that easily when using pen and paper with the sequence 1,1,1,1,2. I think it would be easier to store the last value and last count and iterate over the whole array. If the current variable is different from the last value it means a new sequence starts. Now you can update the start/end of the longest sequence found so far, if the now ended sequence is longer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a shorter, more generic solution. This method takes any array of ints and prints parenthesis around the longest run of numbers. If there are two runs of the same lengths it prints it around the first one.

```
public String makeString(int[] ints) {
  if (ints.length == 0) return ""; // Quit early if there's nothing to do.

  // Initialize variables.
  int lastNumber = ints[0];
  // We keep track of the all time best run. Defaults to first int found.
  int bestStart = 0;
  int bestRun = 1;
  // ... as well as the current run.
  int currentStart = 0;
  int currentRun = 1;
  String s = ""+ints[0];

  // Starting from the second int, we check if the current run is continuing.
  for (int i = 1; i < ints.length; i++) {
    int current = ints[i];
    // If the current run continues, we update currentStart/currentRun, else we reset it.
    if (current == lastNumber) {
      currentRun++;
    } else {
      currentStart = i;
      currentRun = 1;
    }

    // Now we check if the currentRun is better than the best.
    // If so, we update bestStart/bestRun.
    if (currentRun > bestRun) {
      bestStart = currentStart;
      bestRun = currentRun;
    }

    lastNumber = current;
    s += current;
  }

  // Now that we've found it, we insert parenthesis aaaaaaand we're done!
  return s.substring(0, bestStart)
      +"("+s.substring(bestStart, bestStart+bestRun)+")"
      +s.substring(bestStart+bestRun);
}
```